# Есть ли возможность настроить QPainter для qml-ного ChartView?

Tags: qt, qml

Это нужно чтобы при рисовании полупрозрачных линий не было видно их пересечений. По умолчанию, ChartView рисует как на рис.1. Если то же нарисовать в QQuickPaintedItem с ностроенным QPainter::CompositionMode для QPainter, то получается как и хотелось бы (рис.2)
[image: рис. 1]
[image: рис. 2]

Comment: Пожалуй, без минимального воспроизводимого примера вряд ли кто-то возьмется за эту задачу.